# @ConfigProperty on boolean member

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, neo4j, jca

I'm trying to compile and deploy [neo4j-connector](https://github.com/alexsmirnov/neo4j-connector).

Two classes in neo4j-connector-impl (`Neo4jManagedConnection` and `Neo4jResourceAdapter`) have the following annotation:

```
@ConfigProperty
private boolean xa;
```

This compiles fine, but when I try to deploy to glassfish 3.1.1, I get a series of errors:

> [boolean] is not an allowed property value typeat
>   org.glassfish.apf.AnnotationInfo@118944a
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: [boolean] is not an allowed property value typeat org.glassfish.apf.AnnotationInfo@118944a
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:490)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:432)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readRestDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:408)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readDeploymentDescriptors(Archivist.java:383)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:246)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:255)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.open(Archivist.java:216)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.ApplicationFactory.openArchive(ApplicationFactory.java:165)
>           at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:181)
>           at org.glassfish.javaee.core.deployment.DolProvider.load(DolProvider.java:93)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.loadDeployer(ApplicationLifecycle.java:828)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.setupContainerInfos(ApplicationLifecycle.java:770)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:368)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
>           at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:382)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:355)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:370)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1064)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:96)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1244)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1232)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:459)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:209)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:168)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:238)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:828)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:725)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1019)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:225)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
>           at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680) Caused by: [boolean] is not an allowed property value typeat
>   org.glassfish.apf.AnnotationInfo@118944a
>           at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:367)
>           at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:375)
>           at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:289)
>           at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.processAnnotations(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:271)
>           at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:199)
>           at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:134)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.processAnnotations(Archivist.java:606)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.archivist.Archivist.readAnnotations(Archivist.java:445)
>           ... 39 more Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [boolean] is not an allowed property value type
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EnvironmentProperty.checkType(EnvironmentProperty.java:178)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.deployment.EnvironmentProperty.setType(EnvironmentProperty.java:239)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.annotation.handlers.ConfigPropertyHandler.getConfigProperty(ConfigPropertyHandler.java:221)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.annotation.handlers.ConfigPropertyHandler.handleConfigPropertyAnnotation(ConfigPropertyHandler.java:142)
>           at com.sun.enterprise.connectors.deployment.annotation.handlers.ConfigPropertyHandler.processAnnotation(ConfigPropertyHandler.java:91)
>           at org.glassfish.apf.impl.AnnotationProcessorImpl.process(AnnotationProcessorImpl.java:344)
>           ... 46 more

I can come up with ways around it (e.g., add a `setXa(String)` method), but this doesn't feel right: this code has been unchanged since it was committed over a year ago, so why shouldn't it work for me? What could be going wrong here?

Comment: A (somewhat dated, as it refers to j2e 1.4) resource saying that this should work: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/j2ee/1.4/docs/tutorial-update2/doc/JSPIntro8.html (look at table 12-4)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could raise an issue in the github project with the author, Alex Smirnow?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that the properties have to be simple java objects, like `String`, `Integer`, `Long` etc.

`int`, `long`, `boolean` (primitives) seem to have a problem.

Hope this helps